# Does .load() retrieve Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, I have a div with Javascript (and PHP) in it:

```
<div id="getItems">
<script>
    sessionStorage.setItem('numItems', <?php echo $_SESSION['NumItems'];?>);
</script>
</div>
```

I'd like to selectively reload this div, to get the most current value of `numItems`.

Something like:

```
$( "#getItems" ).load( window.location + " #getItems" );
var numItems = sessionStorage.getItem('numItems');
```

Will the .load() method retrieve and run the Javascript within the div?

Or does .load() only pass html into the div?

Comment: That should work, to run the JavaScript *(although I don't like the design)*. Keep in mind PHP executes on the Server before send to your Client's Browser *(so you need `session_start();` before headers are sent)*, jQuery parses after that. If you want to prevent the Client from updating your session then you should just create a Server `$_SESSION`. Use AJAX to communicate to your PHP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameter passed to `.load` didn't contain a selector at the end, then yes, scripts inside will be run.

But since you called `.load` with a selector, any scripts inside will *not* be run. See [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Script Execution
>
> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. **If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.** An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will successfully execute.
>
> ```
> $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
> ```
>
> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> ```
> $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
> ```

Your case is the second, so inline `<script>`s will be stripped out and not run.

If you want to update the value for `NumItems` on the client, don't use `.load` - instead, make a network request to a PHP script which *only* echos `$_SESSION['NumItems']`, and set the response to the `sessionStorage` item.

Comment: Thanks I will take the approach you suggested. Also wanted to point out that you may have made a typo here: "since you called .load with a selector, any scripts inside will be run." I think you meant 'will not' be run, based on the rest of your comment. If so, perhaps edit that part for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The .load() method only loads the following data:

> url
>   Type: String
>   A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>   data
>   Type: PlainObject or String
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>   complete
>   Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>   A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

It appears to me that you can pass in a file-path as an argument to the method and any javascript logic within that file will execute.

However;

> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will successfully execute.

```
$( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
```

> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being
>   loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:

```
$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
```